# powershell -match Unexpect Results

Tags: powershell

i've written a simple PowerShell script that is designed to take a file name and then move the file into a particular folder.

The files in question are forms scanned in as PDF documents.

Within the file name, I have defined a unique string of characters used to help identify which form it is and then my script will sort the file into the correct folder.

I've captured the file name as a string variable.

I am using -match to evaluate the file name string variable and my issue is that match is acting like...well -like.

For example, my script looks for (F1) in the string and if this returns true my script will move the file into a folder named IT Account Requests.

This all works well until my script finds a file with (F10) in the name, as 'match' will evaluate the string and find a match for F1 also.

How can I use 'match' to return true for an exact string block?

I know this may sound like a fairly basic newbie question to ask, but how do I use -match to tell the different between the two file types?

I've scoured the web looking to learn how to force -match to do what I would like but maybe I need a re-think here and use something other than 'match' to gain the result I need?

I appreciate your time reading this.

Code Example:

```
$Master_File_name = "Hardware Request (F10).pdf"

if ($Master_File_name -match "(F1)"){Write-Output "yes"}
if ($Master_File_name -match "(F10)"){Write-Output "yes"}
```

Both if statements return 'yes'

Comment: F10 contains F1, whats unexpected? you don't use `-match` to match exact string, you use `-eq`

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes this is probably my misunderstanding of how -match works I would have thought it only return true if an exact match was found based on the variable I passed to it.  I have tried using -eq however I've found that this doesn't appear to work in my code example.

Comment: To the above commenter, if he did "-eq", it would have to equal the whole filename. Trystan, you can probably use the "-like" operator as well, but I don't know what your whole script looks like.

Comment: Remember to escape your pattern `if($Master_File_Name -match [regex]::Escape('(F1)'))`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I can confirm that this worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen if you can put your comment as an answer I will tick it as the solution to my question.  Thanks Again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-match` does a regular expression based match against your string, meaning that the right-hand side argument is a regex pattern, not a literal string.

In regex, `(F1)` means "match on F and 1, and capture the substring as a separate group".

To match on the literal string `(F1)`, escape the pattern either manually:

```
if($Master_File_Name -match '\(F1\)'){Write-Output 'yes'}
```

or have it done for you automatically using the `Regex.Escape()` method:

```
if($Master_File_Name -match [regex]::Escape('(F1)')){Write-Output 'yes'}
```

Comment: This is a great explanation and I can confirm it works well in my script! Thank you!